# C# Regex Match Tag and text before end of it

Tags: c#, regex, tags

I need to extract tag's and text between them.
Sample text

```
<SampleTag1>Text \r\n More < Text < <\SampleTag1>
```

And I want to get:

- Group1: SampleTag1
- Group2: Text \r\n More < Text <

Now I have:

```
"<(\w+)>([^</]*)"
```

But I't returns only:

- Group1: SampleTag1
- Text \r\n More

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that's not valid XML I guess a regex solution may be valid in your case.

```
<(?<tag>\w+)>(?<text>.*?)</\k{tag}>
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zZ5cZ7/1)

I used a lazy qualtifier (`.*?`) to match as few characters as possible, but since the closing tag is required, it has to match the text inside the tag for the match to succeed. Use with `RegexOptions.Singleline` if you need line break support. This expression won't work if you can nest tags.

(replace `</` with `<\\` if needed)